# Python pow not accepting third input

Tags: python

I have written a function in python which involves the use of pow with three arguments. It was working fine and then I wrote some unrelated code to the same file after which it kept telling my that pow expected two arguments but got three even though the documentation for pow says it can accept three arguments and was working fine before. I am using Python 2.7 . Anyone has any idea as to why this is happening?

Here is the function:

```
def fast_is_prime(p,accuracy=64):
    """
    very quickly checks if a number is prime, is wrong with probability at most
    1/2**(accuracy), accuracy default is 64
    """
    if p == 1:
        return False
    return all(pow(random.randint(1,p-1),p-1,p) == 1 for i in range(accuracy))
```

Comment: Have you named another object `pow`?

Comment: No, there is no other object named pow

Comment: Are you sure? That function runs fine for me.

Comment: Did you do `from math import *`?

Comment: Yes, should that do anything?

Comment: It defines [another `pow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow), which only takes two arguments. This is why [wildcard imports are discouraged](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: Here is the error I am getting: TypeError: pow expected 2 arguments, got 3

Comment: Alright I changed it so that I only imported what I needed and it is now working properly, thank you very much.

Comment: It is the import.  Your function works before, and does not work anymore after importing `from math import *`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I usually don't use a wildcard import, but I've always made an exception for `math` since I figured it'd be unlikely to cause problems. How disappointing that it causes a conflict with a Python built-in!

Comment: @doublep: Would you like to write up the answer?

Comment: You should either import the exact things you need from math (`from math import log`) or import the math module and use it within the code (`import math … math.log`). Using `from math import *` is overriding the built-in `pow` with the one from `math`. Good catch @doublep.  You can always debug with `print(pow.__module__)` which should return `__builtin__` if you want the version with three arguments.

Comment: Seems like you have a user defined method named pow() in your program or in one of those files you are importing. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Credit goes to doublep and jonrsharp in the comments for figuring out the answer)

In your case the built-in function `pow()` was covered up the [`pow()` from the math module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow). Use `import math` (the functions you use from it need to be prefixed with `math.` in this case) or use `from math import X` where X is the particular function you need.

Using `from math import *` imports all of the functions from the math module into the main namespace. Any names in the main namespace will be covered up by the names from the math module. Python Standard Library modules aren't meant to be used like this. This means that importing standard library modules like this can cover up built-in functions. For example [`os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) will cover up `open()` if os is imported that way. Use `import math` or `from math import X` where X is the particular function you need to prevent this.